# Request Format unfamiliar for JSON Payload

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Server is expecting my payload to look like this:

```
{"fields":[
{"name":"name","data":"leslie"},
{"name":"email","data":"leslie@somewhere"},
{"name":"phone","data":"555-555-5555"}]}
```

How to write a payload looks like this?

hi. 
i am failing to write the payload.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'platform': 'web',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip'}

payload = ?????

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload) ,headers=headers)
```

Comment: So what do you have for code so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  To get the best answers, it really helps to ask good questions and show what you have done.  Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The expectation here is that you've tried to solve the problem yourself first. :-)

Comment: hi. 
i am failing to write the payload. 

import requests
import json

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'platform': 'web',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip'}

payload = ?????

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload) ,headers=headers)

Comment: i edit the post for legibility

Comment: erm.... so why aren't you sending the top dict as payload? Or if you did, what happened?